# Como cambio la imagen de un imageView?

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview

Tengo este código y pienso que deberia funcionar, pero al entrar sale

```
    public class MuestraTipos extends AppCompatActivity {
int[] fotos;
ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fotos= new int[]{R.drawable.fondor, R.drawable.fondopop, R.drawable.fondopop};
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_muestra_tipos);
        img= findViewById(R.id.foto);
        try{
            int valor= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
            img.setImageResource(fotos[valor]);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Es muy importante en este caso que agregues el mensaje de error que se muestra en el LogCat, las causas por la cual se cierra la aplicación pueden ser diversas.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregarle a esta linea

```
img= findViewById(R.id.foto);
```

Lo Siguiente:

```
img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);
```

Sin el Casteo correspondiente, no ocurrirá nada.

Comment: Actualmente no es necesario realizar el casting (ImageView).